# Looking for web component to acomplish this (maybe a SELECT or don't know)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm building a web application where I have categories and subcategories. Since I have right now 1900 rows in a table and it's growing up I need a component to show them as follow:

1. A first level should show main categories (those who have not parents)
2. When I pick any of the parents categories then inside the same component I should able to show their children and also give the ability to go back and pick any other category.

Does any one know any kind of component to do this? Maybe a SELECT or something else? Also if any have ideas programmatic then leave here and I'll take into account.

**PS:** I don't know if this is the right place to post this if not apologies and point me in the right direction for the next one.

Comment: Hmm... what about a simple list..that expands..? Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/kTUwR/ just on a larger scale, yes?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the same component ? You could simply populate a second select according to the value selected in the first one.

Comment: [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to fool the user and make him think this is the same component then you can probably do something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/rudEg/).

You'll have to get matching data of selected category from the server, with probably an ajax request and a json object, in order to populate the select.

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  success:function(data){
     $('#item').empty();
     $(data).each(function(){
        $('#item').append($('<option>').val(this.value).text(this.description));
     }
  }
});
```

But still i think the dual select is more convenient for the user. But if your goal is to only display data then displaying items in a select component is a  bad idea. A table or a list would be more appropriate.

Comment: well I don't know how many parent > children I'll have right now it's only four levels so maybe in the future this could be a problem not so sure also don't know how to handle this, will you have a better idea?